# Reduce each consecutive sequence to its value and length

Tags: r, sequence, repeat, reduction

Assume you have a vector with runs of consecutive values:

```
v <- c(1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  1, 1,  3, 3, 3, 3)
```

How can it be best reduced to one value per run and the length of each run. I.e. the first run is `1` repeated two times; 2nd run: `2` repeated four times; 3rd run: `1` repeated two times, and so on:

```
v.df <- data.frame(value = c(1, 2, 1, 3),
                   repetitions = c(3, 4, 2, 4))
```

In a procedural language I might just iterate through a loop and build the data.frame as I go, but with a large dataset in R such an approach is inefficient.  Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

or more simply

```
data.frame(rle(v)[])
```

Comment: That's nice, even more succinct.

Comment: Another ways `data.frame(unclass(rle(v)))` or `as.data.frame.list(rle(v))`

Answer (score 8):

```
with(rle(v), data.frame(values, lengths))
```

should get you what you need.

```
values lengths
     1       3
     2       4
     1       2
     3       4
```

Comment: That is exactly the function I was thinking of; I just couldn't remember the name for the life of me!  Thank you so much.